# How to run a part of Code and upDate UI even when the iPhone App is BackGround

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, gps

A piece of  code need to be executed even after the iPhone app sent to background.
Based on the values the UI need to get changed.
When I bring the App to foreground.It need to be updated with the changes made at the background time.

Eg.When I sent a GPS application to BackGround.It need to receive the positions accordingly and update the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know, you may not update the UI while in background (As per memory guidelines, you should release any unused/cached portions of your interface). However, you can schedule your update to the moments after your app is reactivated.

Comment: ThankYou @mja ,How to track changes while the application is background.The app need to be notified by the change.

Comment: you just need to start `[locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];`, your app will be woken up from the background for a small period of time. This is important, do not do a lot of stuff (e.g. network access, etc) because your app might be terminated if you fail to finish the work. If you have to, i guess you might do a small change to the GUI, but be sure it's quick.  If you need precise position information, you can use the standard background location service and declare this by adding _location_ UIBackgroundMode in your plist.

Comment: Thank You very much for the support . I got the required .